# Spring Data Neo4J 4.0.0: BeforeSaveEvent not firing?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm trying to capture the BeforeSaveEvent when setting up Neo4J in Spring, so that I can call a method `beforeSave()` on the class that is being saved. Unfortunately, it seems like its not being registered as a listener as non of my print statements are being executed.

Ideas appreciated.

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.noxgroup.nitro")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class NitroNeo4jConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Neo4jServer neo4jServer () {
        System.setProperty("username", "neo4j");
        System.setProperty("password", "*************");
        return new RemoteServer("http://localhost:7474");
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("com.noxgroup.nitro.domain");
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent> beforeSaveEventApplicationListener() {
        return new ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onApplicationEvent(BeforeSaveEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Listening to event");
                Object entity = event.getEntity();
                if (entity instanceof NitroNode) {
                     ((NitroNode)entity).beforeSave();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not picking it up");
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

These events are fired by Neo4jTemplate (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.0.0.M1/reference/html/#_data_manipulation_events_formerly_lifecycle_events), so that's what you'll have to use to trigger the save.

In your configuration `NitroNeo4jConfiguration` include

```
@Bean
public Neo4jOperations getNeo4jTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new Neo4jTemplate(getSession());
}
```

and in your application,

```
@Autowired
private Neo4jOperations neo4jTemplate;
```

which is then used to save

```
neo4jTemplate.save(person);
```

Comment: it works fine, but if I created a repository interface and call the save method on the repository, then the event would not be fire, as I would expect.

Comment: A Jira issue has been filed for this: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-710.

Comment: It's been a long time about this issue...any news about the change of firing events saving through repositories? Or use the template is the way to proceed? Thanks